# Show mtime of a file in another branch

Tags: linux, git

Using `git ls-files --debug` or `stat` command, you can see the mtime (last modified time) of a file **in a current branch** (strictly in a current commit).

```sh
$ git ls-files --debug main.py 
main.py
  ctime: 1626910912:885869194
  mtime: 1626910912:869124612
  dev: 16777234 ino: 8580291
  uid: 501  gid: 20
  size: 4832    flags: 0
```

```sh
$ stat main.py 
  File: main.py
  Size: 4832        Blocks: 16         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 1000012h/16777234d  Inode: 8580291     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (  501/     user)   Gid: (   20/   staff)
Access: 2021-07-22 09:08:43.090154548 +0900
Modify: 2021-07-22 08:41:52.869124612 +0900
Change: 2021-07-22 08:41:52.885869194 +0900
 Birth: 2021-07-22 08:41:52.868783790 +0900
```

Then is there any way to see this information for the same file **in another branch (another commit)**?

---

**Workarounds**

Currently I have two workarounds, both of which I don't think are beautiful solutions.

- First `git checkout <commit>` and then `git ls-files --debug <file>`.
- First `git blame <commit> <file>`. The output includes many timestamps. Parsing them, pick the latest timestamp (using `cut`, `sort`, `sed`, etc.).

Comment: Note that Git does not *store* modification times in commits, only in the index as a side effect of storing `lstat` cache data for the current checkout (so it can tell if you've modified the file since the last time Git cached it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get modification time in another branch with :

```
git log -1 --pretty="format:%ci" branch-name -- file-name
```

Comment: For the future reader: Strictly speaking, `%ci` doesn't correspond to mtime as it represents *committer date* (i.e. the time you commit the file). However, this one line command is beautiful and meets my needs. Thank you :)